# Creation of debugging tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

There are quite a few questions of Quantum Computing Stack Exchange which are often new user's asking help  with `Q#` or `Qiskit` code. These questions are mostly filed based on the languages. However I feel that a lot of these questions are essentially debugging/ error hunting exercises. I think these questions which should be tagged `debugging` in order to clarify the nature of these questions.

Comment: Be careful with [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: we also have the `programming` tag for such questions. However, I would argue that questions that are really only about debugging should be closed as "not enough effort", as they are unlikely to be useful to anyone other than the asker, so I don't see a "debugging" tag as very beneficial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be useful to distinguish debugging questions from other types of Qiskit or Q# questions.

I do doubt that many people will want to "follow" or "subscribe" to the emails for a "debugging" tag at this time, since Qiskit and Q# are still relatively new compared to other programming languages and they won't have a lot of long-time veteran experts who might love to know whenever someone can be helped with a debugging problem. In fact I worry that people might see the tag "debugging" and be immediately reluctant to open the question rather than moving on to reading the next question's title, because who loves to do debugging for a new language?

In any case, soon enough if you answer enough questions you'll have the ability to create tags, and I think you'd be welcome to do that and see how it turns out.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with tags which prevent people from looking at certain types of questions: It allows to filter for content people are interested in.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch You're basically saying that it's good to have a debugging tag so that people that don't like debugging questions, can avoid questions with that tag?

Comment: Precisely.  This is by design in SE: Otherwise, why would it be possible to ignore tags?  (And this is exactly what tags *should* be fore: Filtering content!  Having content which is better adjusted to my interests will make me come back more likely.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch If it's useful for you, there's no problem with having a debugging tag. My impression was that OP wanted this tag to "find" questions rather than to "avoid" them (but it's just a guess). I don't mind if you make a debugging tag, or if OP goes out and earns enough reputation to create it.